# Libraw doesn't use camera-provided white balance

Tags: libraw

I tried this:

```
    LibRaw iProcessor;
    iProcessor.open_file(filename);
    iProcessor.unpack();
    iProcessor.imgdata.params.use_auto_wb = 1;
    iProcessor.imgdata.params.use_camera_wb = 1;
    iProcessor.dcraw_process();
    iProcessor.raw2image();
```

But this produces a wrong white balance (always too green).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to remove the "raw2image" part.